# PHP mySQL code posting extra rows to database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

**SECOND EDIT**
It seems that upon loading the page, not when submitting, that the two entries (blank rows) are added to my database. I'm really struggling to find my problem here but I have a feeling it's a fairly stupid error.

I'm having an issue with my php/mysql code posting extra blank rows along with what it's supposed to post. The code for the validation of the data from my form an for the transmission of the info to the database is below. Every time I enter data in my form and submit it it works fine, however it adds extra rows to the tblLocation, the tblWhere works fine. Can anyone lead me in the right direction here? Let me know if you need more of my code.

**CODE IS AS FOLLOWS**

```
if (isset($_POST['butSubmit'])) {

// set variables to data from form    
$user= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtUser"]);
$fName= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtFname"]);
$lName= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtLname"]);
$email= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtEmail"]);
$date= date(DATE_RFC822);
$street= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtStreet"]);
$city= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtCity"]);
$state= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lstStates"]);
$zip= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtZip"]);

    //handle html characters
$user = htmlentities($user, ENT_QUOTES);
$fName = htmlentities($fName, ENT_QUOTES);
$lName = htmlentities($lName, ENT_QUOTES);
$email = htmlentities($email, ENT_QUOTES);
$date = htmlentities($date, ENT_QUOTES);
$street = htmlentities($street, ENT_QUOTES);
$city = htmlentities($city, ENT_QUOTES);
$state = htmlentities($state, ENT_QUOTES);
$zip = htmlentities($zip, ENT_QUOTES);
$errorMsg=array();


// initiate testing procedures for form contents 
if($user==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter your Username";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($user); /* test for non-valid  data */
    if (!$valid){ 
        $error_msg[]="Username must contain only letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces, dashes(-), and apostrophes (').";
    }
}

if($fName==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter your First Name";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($fName); /* test for non-valid  data */
    if (!$valid){ 
        $error_msg[]="First Name must contain only letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces, dashes(-), and apostrophes (').";
    }
}

    if($lName==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter your Last Name";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($lName); /* test for non-valid  data */
    if (!$valid){ 
        $error_msg[]="Last Name must contain only letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces, dashes(-), and apostrophes (').";
    }
}

if($email==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter your Email Address";
} elseif (!verifyEmail($email)){
    $errorMsg[]="Correct eMail format is ( example@anysite.com )";
}

    if($street==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter your Street Address";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($street); /* test for non-valid  data */
    if (!$valid){ 
        $error_msg[]="Street Address must contain only letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces, dashes(-), and apostrophes (').";
    }
}

    if($city==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter a City";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($city); /* test for non-valid  data */
    if (!$valid){ 
        $error_msg[]="City must contain only letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces, dashes(-), and apostrophes (').";
    }
}

    if($state==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please choose a State";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($state); /* test for non-valid  data */
    }
}

    if($errorMsg){
    echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach($errorMsg as $err){
        echo "<li style='color: #ff6666'>" . $err . "</li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
} else { 

                 mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblWhere (pk_Username, fldFirstName, fldLastName, fldAdminLevel, fldTotalPosts, fldDateJoined, fldEmail) VALUES ('$user', '$fName', '$lName', '4', '0', '$date', '$email')");
                                if (mysql_errno()) {
                            echo $sql . "<br/>\n" . mysql_error();
                                }

                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblLocation (fk_Username, fldStreet, fldCity, fldState, fldZip) VALUES ('$user', '$street', '$city', '$state', '$zip')");
                                if (mysql_errno()) {
                            echo $sql . "<br/>\n" . mysql_error();
                                }
}
mysql_close();
print $user;
```

**EDIT**
Here is the full code, maybe this will help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>

<title>CS148 "Where Are You From?" Page</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="author" content="Stephen B. Wakita" />

<meta name='description' content='Form to gather information for CS148 PHP Form Assignment. The     javascript functions for validation are from Easy! Designs, LLC easydesigns.net and few by Robert Erickson.'/>

<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="mystyle.css"
  type="text/css"
  media="screen" />

<script src="validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.onload = Initialize;

function Initialize(){
  if (!document.getElementById || !document.createElement || !document.createTextNode)
    return;

  var objForm = document.getElementById('frmRegister');
  objForm.onsubmit= function(){return fblnVerified(this);};
}

function reSetForm(){
    document.getElementById('txtFname').style.background='#fff';
    document.getElementById('txtLname').style.background='#fff';
    document.getElementById('txtEmail').style.background='#fff';    
    document.getElementById('lstStates').style.background='#fff';
    document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML="";
}

function fblnVerified(theForm){
        reSetForm();
        returnStatus = true;
      errorMsg = "";
        numErrors = 0;


    if (isEmpty(theForm.txtFname.value)) {
        document.getElementById('txtFname').style.background='#FF6';
        errorMsg += "<li>Please enter your first name.</li>";
        numErrors += 1;
        returnStatus = false;
    }

    if (isEmpty(theForm.txtLname.value)) {
        document.getElementById('txtLname').style.background='#FF6';
        errorMsg += "<li>Please Enter your last name.</li>";
        numErrors += 1;
        returnStatus = false;
    } else if (!isWithinRange(theForm.txtLname.value.length, 2, 45)){
        document.getElementById('txtLname').style.background='#FF6';
        errorMsg += "<li>Last name must contain at least two characters.</li>";
        numErrors += 1;
        returnStatus = false;
    }

    if (isEmpty(theForm.txtEmail.value)) {
        document.getElementById('txtEmail').style.background='#FF6';
        errorMsg += "<li>Please enter your email address.</li>";
        numErrors += 1;
        returnStatus = false;
    }else if (!isEmailAddress(theForm.txtEmail.value)){
        document.getElementById('txtEmail').style.background='#FF6';
        errorMsg += "<li>You have entered your email in an invalid format, please use this format: example@example.xxx </li>";
        numErrors += 1;     
        returnStatus = false;
    }

    if(returnStatus == false){
        msg1 = "Your form is incomplete or incorrect. There are " + numErrors + " errors. ";
        msg1 += "Please look for the highlighted items.";
        msg = "<p>" + msg1 + "</p><ol class='missing' id='errorMessages'></ol>";
        document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = msg;

        document.getElementById('errorMessages').innerHTML= errorMsg;
        alert(msg1);
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
    return returnStatus;
}
-->
</script>
</head>
<body class="bodycolor">
<div id="content">
<div id="errors">
</div>

<form action="form.php" 
        method="post"
        id="frmWhere">


<fieldset class="wrapper">
<legend>Where are you from?</legend>
<p>Please answer the following survey. Required fields are marked in <span    class="required">red</span>.</p>

<fieldset class="intro">
<legend>Please complete the following survey.</legend>

<fieldset class="main">
<legend>Contact Information</legend>                    
<fieldset class="info"> 

    <label for="txtUser" class="required">Username</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtUser" name="txtUser" value="" tabindex="260"
            size="30" maxlength="26" onfocus="this.select()" />

    <label for="txtFname" class="required">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtFname" name="txtFname" value="" tabindex="261"
            size="55" maxlength="45" onfocus="this.select()" />


    <label for="txtLname" class="required">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtLname" name="txtLname" value="" tabindex="262"
            size="55" maxlength="45" onfocus="this.select()" />


    <label for="txtEmail" class="required">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" value="" tabindex="263"
            size="55" maxlength="45" onfocus="this.select()" />

  <label for="txtstreet" class="required">Street Address</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtStreet" name="txtStreet" value="" tabindex="264"
            size="55" maxlength="45" onfocus="this.select()" />

    <label for="txtCity" class="required">City</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtCity" name="txtCity" value="" tabindex="265"
            size="55" maxlength="45" onfocus="this.select()" />

    <select id="lstStates" name="lstStates" tabindex="266" size="1">
<option value="ZZ">None</option>
<option value="">-- UNITED STATES --</option>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="CO">Colorado</option>
<option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
<option value="DE">Delaware</option>
<option value="FL">Florida</option>
<option value="GA">Georgia</option>
<option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
<option value="ID">Idaho</option>
<option value="IL">Illinois</option>
<option value="IN">Indiana</option>
<option value="IA">Iowa</option>
<option value="KS">Kansas</option>
<option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
<option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
<option value="ME">Maine</option>
<option value="MD">Maryland</option>
<option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
<option value="MI">Michigan</option>
<option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
<option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
<option value="MO">Missouri</option>
<option value="MT">Montana</option>
<option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
<option value="NV">Nevada</option>
<option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
<option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
<option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
<option value="NY">New York</option>
<option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
<option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
<option value="OH">Ohio</option>
<option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
<option value="OR">Oregon</option>
<option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
<option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
<option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
<option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
<option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
<option value="TX">Texas</option>
<option value="UT">Utah</option>
<option value="VT">Vermont</option>
<option value="VA">Virginia</option>
<option value="WA">Washington</option>
<option value="DC">Washington, DC</option>
<option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
<option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>

<option value="">-- CANADA --</option>
<option value="AB">Alberta</option>
<option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
<option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
<option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
<option value="NF">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
<option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
<option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
<option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
<option value="ON">Ontario</option>
<option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
<option value="PQ">Quebec</option>
<option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
<option value="YT">Yukon Territory</option>
<option value="">-- OTHER --</option>
<option value="OT">Other</option>
    </select>

<label for="txtZip" class="required">ZIP Code</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtZip" name="txtZip" value="" tabindex="267"
            size="6" maxlength="6" onfocus="this.select()" />       


<fieldset class="buttons">
<legend></legend>               
<input type="submit" id="butSubmit" name="butSubmit" value="Submit" 
            tabindex="991" class="button"/>

<input type="reset" id="butReset" name="butReset" value="Reset Form" 
            tabindex="993" class="button" onclick="reSetForm()" />
</fieldset>                 

</fieldset>
</fieldset>
</fieldset>
</form>
</?php

include ("validation_functions.php");

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$dbh=mysql_connect('webdb.uvm.edu','swakita','password');

if (!$dbh)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db('SWAKITA', $dbh);



if (isset($_POST['butSubmit'])) {

    //handle html characters
$user = htmlentities($user, ENT_QUOTES);
$fName = htmlentities($fName, ENT_QUOTES);
$lName = htmlentities($lName, ENT_QUOTES);
$email = htmlentities($email, ENT_QUOTES);
$date = htmlentities($date, ENT_QUOTES);
$street = htmlentities($street, ENT_QUOTES);
$city = htmlentities($city, ENT_QUOTES);
$state = htmlentities($state, ENT_QUOTES);
$zip = htmlentities($zip, ENT_QUOTES);
$errorMsg=array();

// set variables to data from form    
$user= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtUser"]);
$fName= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtFname"]);
$lName= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtLname"]);
$email= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtEmail"]);
$date= date(DATE_RFC822);
$street= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtStreet"]);
$city= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtCity"]);
$state= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lstStates"]);
$zip= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtZip"]);



// initiate testing procedures for form contents 
if($user==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter your Username";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($user); /* test for non-valid  data */
    if (!$valid){ 
        $error_msg[]="Username must contain only letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces, dashes(-), and apostrophes (').";
    }
}

if($fName==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter your First Name";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($fName); /* test for non-valid  data */
    if (!$valid){ 
        $error_msg[]="First Name must contain only letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces, dashes(-), and apostrophes (').";
    }
}

    if($lName==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter your Last Name";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($lName); /* test for non-valid  data */
    if (!$valid){ 
        $error_msg[]="Last Name must contain only letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces, dashes(-), and apostrophes (').";
    }
}

if($email==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter your Email Address";
} elseif (!verifyEmail($email)){
    $errorMsg[]="Correct eMail format is ( example@anysite.com )";
}

    if($street==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter your Street Address";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($street); /* test for non-valid  data */
    if (!$valid){ 
        $error_msg[]="Street Address must contain only letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces, dashes(-), and apostrophes (').";
    }
}

    if($city==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter a City";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($city); /* test for non-valid  data */
    if (!$valid){ 
        $error_msg[]="City must contain only letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces, dashes(-), and apostrophes (').";
    }
}

    if($state==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please choose a State";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($state); /* test for non-valid  data */
    }
}

    if($errorMsg){
    echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach($errorMsg as $err){
        echo "<li style='color: #ff6666'>" . $err . "</li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
} else { 

                 mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblWhere (pk_Username, fldFirstName, fldLastName, fldAdminLevel, fldTotalPosts, fldDateJoined, fldEmail) VALUES ('$user', '$fName', '$lName', '4', '0', '$date', '$email')");
                                if (mysql_errno()) {
                            echo $sql . "<br/>\n" . mysql_error();
                                }

                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblLocation (fk_Username, fldStreet, fldCity, fldState, fldZip) VALUES ('$user', '$street', '$city', '$state', '$zip')");
                                if (mysql_errno()) {
                            echo $sql . "<br/>\n" . mysql_error();
                                }
}
mysql_close();
print $user;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont know why youre getting dupe rows but you should do the `htmlentities` calls BEFORE the `mysql_real_escape_string` calls. Functionally i can think of an instance where it would make a difference but from a logic perspective the db escaping should be the last thing you do before using the value in a query.

Comment: Hmm, the provided code should not duplicate entries, strange. Do you have a redirect somewhere else in your script by chance? You don't get a warning in your browser saying you are refreshing a page with post data etc? Also, does it duplicate the entry exactly or does it insert blank values? Where is $sql defined? heh, sorry if these are pointless Q's :P

Comment: @BenAshton It doesn't duplicate enetries, it posts blank values along with the entry. I added the full code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs the mysql query outside of the POST check, the mysql query runs no matter what because `$errorMsg` is not being returned.

Move your mysql logic inside the `if (isset($_POST['butSubmit'])) {` part of your code.

```
<?php

include ("validation_functions.php");

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$dbh=mysql_connect('webdb.uvm.edu','swakita','password');

if (!$dbh)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db('SWAKITA', $dbh);



if (isset($_POST['butSubmit'])) {

    //handle html characters
$user = htmlentities($user, ENT_QUOTES);
$fName = htmlentities($fName, ENT_QUOTES);
$lName = htmlentities($lName, ENT_QUOTES);
$email = htmlentities($email, ENT_QUOTES);
$date = htmlentities($date, ENT_QUOTES);
$street = htmlentities($street, ENT_QUOTES);
$city = htmlentities($city, ENT_QUOTES);
$state = htmlentities($state, ENT_QUOTES);
$zip = htmlentities($zip, ENT_QUOTES);
$errorMsg=array();

// set variables to data from form    
$user= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtUser"]);
$fName= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtFname"]);
$lName= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtLname"]);
$email= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtEmail"]);
$date= date(DATE_RFC822);
$street= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtStreet"]);
$city= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtCity"]);
$state= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lstStates"]);
$zip= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtZip"]);



// initiate testing procedures for form contents 
if($user==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter your Username";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($user); /* test for non-valid  data */
    if (!$valid){ 
        $error_msg[]="Username must contain only letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces, dashes(-), and apostrophes (').";
    }
}

if($fName==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter your First Name";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($fName); /* test for non-valid  data */
    if (!$valid){ 
        $error_msg[]="First Name must contain only letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces, dashes(-), and apostrophes (').";
    }
}

    if($lName==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter your Last Name";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($lName); /* test for non-valid  data */
    if (!$valid){ 
        $error_msg[]="Last Name must contain only letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces, dashes(-), and apostrophes (').";
    }
}

if($email==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter your Email Address";
} elseif (!verifyEmail($email)){
    $errorMsg[]="Correct eMail format is ( example@anysite.com )";
}

    if($street==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter your Street Address";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($street); /* test for non-valid  data */
    if (!$valid){ 
        $error_msg[]="Street Address must contain only letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces, dashes(-), and apostrophes (').";
    }
}

    if($city==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please enter a City";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($city); /* test for non-valid  data */
    if (!$valid){ 
        $error_msg[]="City must contain only letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces, dashes(-), and apostrophes (').";
    }
}

    if($state==""){
    $errorMsg[]="Please choose a State";
} else {
    $valid = verifyAlphaNum ($state); /* test for non-valid  data */
    }


    if($errorMsg){
    echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach($errorMsg as $err){
        echo "<li style='color: #ff6666'>" . $err . "</li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
} else { 

                 mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblWhere (pk_Username, fldFirstName, fldLastName, fldAdminLevel, fldTotalPosts, fldDateJoined, fldEmail) VALUES ('$user', '$fName', '$lName', '4', '0', '$date', '$email')");
                                if (mysql_errno()) {
                            echo $sql . "<br/>\n" . mysql_error();
                                }

                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblLocation (fk_Username, fldStreet, fldCity, fldState, fldZip) VALUES ('$user', '$street', '$city', '$state', '$zip')");
                                if (mysql_errno()) {
                            echo $sql . "<br/>\n" . mysql_error();
                                }
    }
}
mysql_close();
print $user;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was holding me up and I was starting to go insane. After following your change advice it is now working flawlessly.

Comment: No problem, if a piece of code is running that you don't expect, always check your conditionals first ;)

Answer (score 1):

PHP Mysql won't insert blank rows magically so you may check what you are really trying to INSERT, or using some debug *echo $query* statements just before your query, or even better using *print_r(debug_backtrace())*